# Mirror displays on Mint 15 login screen

Tags: linux-mint, display-settings, display

I have the *Mirror Displays* enabled on my Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon 64-bit box, which has a GTX 680 graphics card installed with recommended drivers. I selected [the top green one in this screenshot](http://linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/olivia/mintdrivers.png).

However, when on the login screen, the display is not mirrored; it's displayed on the primary monitor only.

I really would like to have the WebGL clouds (the flyover one) MDM login screen projected on a 108″ screen before login. Is there any way I could do this?

---

**Edits for updates:**

I notice that the *Mirror Displays* setting is account-specific. Is there a "default" user at the login screen whose settings I could tweak to enable this? I've tried `sudo su -l mdm` in an attempt to `cinnamon-settings` the display to mirrored, but `sudo su -l mdm` has no effect (very strangely): I retain my shell prompt, and a single `exit` kills the terminal.

Comment: *(xpost [Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=143682))*

Comment: Which are the "recommended drivers"?

Comment: In Mint, I go to the new Driver Manager, and it asks which drivers I want for the 680. One has the text "(recommended)" in green.

Comment: And you chose which driver?

Comment: I chose the driver with the "recommended" text on it. I'm not at the box right now, but [it appears that the recommended driver for the 680 is the nvidia-310 driver](http://linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/olivia/mintdrivers.png). I changed it *from* the default nouveau driver *to* the recommended driver.

Comment: Ok, the nvidia driver has entirely different setup options to the default drivers. Unfortunately my experience is with ATI cards, so I can't help you.

Comment: No one? No one?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to change the screen resolution in the Ubuntu login screen, and ran across this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution

Basically, lightdm has a config file, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, and you can use the variable `display-setup-script` to set up a script that can do whatever you like with the resolution, mirroring, etc.

I don't know what login program Mint uses, but does it have a similar option somewhere? I don't know, but I think the NVidia driver understands `xrandr`, and if it doesn't it may have it's own CLI configuration tool.

Sorry I can't be more helpful.